# Flutter Amplify with SAML

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js, amplify-ios, flutter-aws-amplify

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter#ios-platform-setup

Im trying to find out if its possible to use SAML with Flutter Amplify plugin

I only see documentation on how to do this with native iOS and Android

How would this be done with Flutter

is it just as simple as updating to awsconfiguration.json to include your SAML info?

```json
{
    "IdentityManager": {
        ...
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        ...
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        ...
    },
    "Auth": {
        "Default": {
            "OAuth": {
                "WebDomain": "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN.auth.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com", // Do not include the https:// prefix
                "AppClientId": "YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID",
                "SignInRedirectURI": "myapp://",
                "SignOutRedirectURI": "myapp://",
                "Scopes": ["openid", "email"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then just calling `Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI();` ?

or am i missing something else that is needed?

or is this not possible with Flutter Amplify yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out all i needed was the correct OAuth config values and simply calling `signInWithWebUI()`

Comment: what were the correct OAuth config values? having trouble with the SignInRedirectURI? any thoughts